# Can't edit table row in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, row

I've just had an issue with a client's site they couldn't login to an admin area I built for them. I verified this and went straight into the database via phpmyadmin.

I thought I'd try to edit the admin password and see if something has gone wrong here. I've clicked edit (pencil icon) however I don't get the row to edit I get the following...

Column | Type | Function | Null | Value

and a go button, no edit options, no row data, I click go and get an error:

```
tbl_replace.php: Missing parameter: goto
```

I'm guessing there is some kind of database issue going on here. I've tried a Check Table and an Analyze Table, with no results output.

Not really sure what's going on here, I've never come across this before.

Any ideas? Sorry if it's a bit vague I've tried to include as much info as I could as simply as I could.

[UPDATE]

I think I've found the culprit to a few issues on my vps, including database and my clients website etc. I found that my tmp directory is full. Old sessions and misc files not being cleared. This could very well be the cause. I have one file '.cpanel_easy-.bLfpq2ZYoTbdcY_c' that I can't identify that is taking up a whole lot of space, if I knew what this was I could possibly fix my issue.

Comment: do you have sufficient privileges in the database ?

Comment: @swapnesh - I would assume so I created the database with the same user (All privileges set to full).

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the issue I was having was caused by the tmp directory on my VPS being full. It was filled with old temporary install files and a bunch of sessions (hundreds) and other miscellaneous files mainly from software updates but a whole bunch from various Wordpress installations, I'm guessing plugins with some messy coding that don't clean up after themselves.

Thanks to those that helped out.